# Hide/Collapse animated gif images in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-office, chat, microsoft-teams, slack, animated-gif

When my coworkers post gifs in the team chat, I roll on the floor laughing.

I then usually "collapse" the gif so that it doesn't continue repeating forever in the background while I'm trying to work.

In Slack, this can be done via the `/collapse` [slash command](https://slack.com/help/articles/201259356-Use-built-in-slash-commands):

> `/collapse`: Collapse all inline images and video in the current channel (opposite of `/expand`)

Or by clicking the small arrow next to the image/gif to collapse it.

---

My org has now moved from Slack to Microsoft Teams. The gif-posting has continued unabated.

In Teams I see no way to collapse images or gifs.

- How can I hide a gif from the screen on a per-user basis?
- Can I pause the gif animation?
- Can images be collapsed in Microsoft Teams?

I'm not interested in admin policy changes that disable gifs for the entire channel. I just want to hide them from my display.

Answer (score 2):

Teams users have been asking for this option for years, but Microsoft
sticks to the concept that this is an admin option, rather
than a user option.

So currently, blocking GIFs is only possible in the browser with an extension
like Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey.

Here is an example
[userscript](https://gist.github.com/anevins12/6d4c30800df981dccc36e26b908a7cad)
that will hide all GIFs:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Remove emojis & remove gifs
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @include     *://*teams.microsoft.com/*
// @version      0.1
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    var styles,
        stylesTag = document.createElement('style');
    
    styles = '[class*="animated-emoticon"] { display: none; }';
    styles += '.stopped-gif, .playing-gif { display: none !important; }';
    
    // Add styles to tag
    stylesTag.textContent = styles;
    
    // Append tag to DOM
    document.head.appendChild(stylesTag);
    
})();
```

Comment: This solution is only for the web browser client, not the Teams desktop app, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I don't know of a non-admin method.